# Selecting based on specific days in time series and another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that can be represented like this:

```
tdate <- rep(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"),as.Date("2000/3/31"),"days"),3)
tcity <- c(rep("New York",91),rep("Boston",91),rep("Miami",91))
tval1 <- rep(seq(1,91,1),3)

tdf <- data.frame(tdate,tcity,tval1)
```

The tval1 column is actually given to me as month-to-date values. I want to 'undo' this and get the values per day for each month that I have for each different city. In other words the way tval1 is given to me is as a cumulative sum and I want to undo that sum and get the individual values. Since they are month-to-date values, the values will get reset for each month. What I want is 'ntval' as below:

```
       tdate    tcity tval1 ntval
1 2000-01-01 New York     1     1
2 2000-01-02 New York     2     1
3 2000-01-03 New York     3     1
4 2000-01-04 New York     4     1
5 2000-01-05 New York     5     1
6 2000-01-06 New York     6     1
```

I can do this with a for loop but that really seems the worst way to do it. Is there any way to do this without a for loop?

I am at a big loss, logically, how to deal with the time series. Any help and advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what exactly `tval` means and what you need to do. `tval` just needs to restart for each month?

Comment: Maybe `diff(tdf$tval1)`? and use `c()` to add an extra value to the top or bottom. or `ave(tdf$tval1, tdf$tcity, diff)` to get values by city if that is important.

Comment: I tried using the ave method but it complained that `unique() applies only to vectors` and I don't know how to get around that.

Comment: @DarshanBaral thanks for the suggestion. It seems to work except at the start of a new month. I updated the example data frame in my original question to show that for the first of Feb, the value is -90. This should just be the value that exists on the first of Feb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand completely. Try this and let me know if it worked

```
#Create a new column for grouping by combining year, month, anc city
tdf$city_year_month = paste(as.character(strftime(tdf$tdate, format = "%Y" )),
            as.character(strftime(tdf$tdate, format = "%m" )), tdf$tcity, sep = "_")

#Sort by the newly created column           
tdf <- tdf[with(tdf, order(city_year_month)), ]

#Split by the grouping in new column and calculate differences
tdf$ntval1 = unlist(sapply(split(tdf, f = tdf$city_year_month), 
        function(x) c(min(x$tval1),diff(x$tval1, lag = 1, differences = 1))))
```

Comment: Wonderful! That works great. I'm still pretty new to R, so can you help me understand what is happening in the sapply (if that is allowed on SO)?

Comment: `sapply` allows applying a function over a list. It is basically `R` way to make loops compact/readable. In this case, `split(...)` subsets `tdf` into different list based on the new column we created. Then `sapply` applies the function  by looping over the elements in each list. Try running each command separately to understand what's going on.